# Efficient implementation of double for-loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I am new to R and I was wondering if there is any more efficient implementation of the following setting? Time series length (x,y) is around 5000 and h != nrow(q).

```
set.seed(1)
h = 21
x <- rnorm(5e3, 1)
y <- rnorm(5e3, 2)

q <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9)
qx <- quantile(x, probs = q)
qx <- expand.grid(qx, qx)
qy <- quantile(y, probs = q)
qy <- expand.grid(qy, qy)
q <- expand.grid(q, q)

f <- function(z, l, qz) {
n <- length(z)
1/(n - l) * sum((z[1:(n-l)] <= qz[[1]]) * (z[(1+l):n] <= qz[[2]])) - prod(q[i,])
}

sum = 0
for (i in 1:h) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(q)) {
    sum = sum + (f(x, l = i, qx[j,]) - f(y, l = i, qy[j,]))^2
  }
}
sum
# 0.0008698279
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would probably be easier to help you if you explained in words what the purpose of the code is.

Comment: @JuliusVainora the purpose of the code is to calculate some distance measure (for clustering) between time series x and y based on covariances of indicators of estimated quantiles. See [https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11634-015-0208-8.pdf](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11634-015-0208-8.pdf) pp. 395-396, Equations (3) and (6) for details.

Answer (score 0):

One faster alternative to loops might be under some circumstances a `sapply` function.
This function works as follows: for each element of a vector perform some function.

Aternatively, you could take a look at a `foreach` package which offers some fast looping.

Here is an example using sapply: depending on what exactly you need, you might want to use either of the functions. Also, sapply is just one of the faster ways of doing this, not necessarily the fastest.

```
# setup from the question
set.seed(1)
h = 1
x <- rnorm(5e3, 1)
y <- rnorm(5e3, 2)

q <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9)
qx <- quantile(x, probs = q)
qx <- expand.grid(qx, qx)
qy <- quantile(y, probs = q)
qy <- expand.grid(qy, qy)
q <- expand.grid(q, q)

f <- function(z, l, qz) {
  n <- length(z)
  1/(n - l) * sum((z[1:(n-l)] <= qz[[1]]) * (z[(1+l):n] <= qz[[2]])) - prod(q[i,])
}

# load microbenchmark library for comparison of execution times
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark({
  # the version from question with for loop
  sum = 0
  for (i in 1:h) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(q)) {
      sum = sum + (f(x, l = i, qx[j,]) - f(y, l = i, qy[j,]))^2
    }
  }
},
{
# using sapply and storing to object. this will give you h*j matrix as well as the sum
sum = 0
sapply(1:h, function(i) sapply(1:nrow(q), function(j) {sum <<- sum + (f(x, l = i, qx[j,]) - f(y, l = i, qy[j,]))^2}))
},
{
# use sapply and sum the output
sum(sapply(1:h, function(i) sapply(1:nrow(q), function(j) {(f(x, l = i, qx[j,]) - f(y, l = i, qy[j,]))^2})))},
# run each code 200 times to get the time comparison
times = 200
)
```